# Filter based on two checkbox values

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, filter, userform

The following code filters a sheet Column (`filterColumn`) by a String (`filterEntry`). Depending on the selection of two checkboxes (`CheckBoxNR1` & `CheckBoxAI1`) in a userform this should then apply a secondary filter to Column E.

No matter the values of the two Check Boxes (`CheckBoxNR1` & `CheckBoxAI1`) this filters **out** "NEEDS RESOURCE" and " AWAITING INFO" from Column E.

What I am trying to achieve:

- "NEEDS RESOURCE" is only filtered out if `CheckBoxNR1 = False`
- "AWAITING INFO" is only filtered out if `CheckBoxAI1 = False`

When both Check Boxes = True then no filters should be applied to Column E.

```vb
'Filter for Team Report
If TeamReportBtnClick = True Then
    Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:=filterEntry
    If CheckBoxAI1 = False And CheckBoxNR1 = False Then
        Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>NEEDS RESOURCE", Criteria2:="<>AWAITING INFO", Operator:=xlAnd
    ElseIf CheckBoxAI1 = True And CheckBoxNR1 = False Then
        Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>NEEDS RESOURCE"
    ElseIf CheckBoxAI1 = False And CheckBoxNR1 = True Then
        Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>AWAITING INFO"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Do you clear the filters before applying these?

Comment: It is a brand new sheet generated each time with no filters applied prior to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was missing was a reference to the name of the Userform on which the Check Box existed (Userform is called `Reports`)

```
    If TeamReportBtnClick = True Then
        Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:=filterEntry
            If Reports.CheckBoxAI1 = False And Reports.CheckBoxNR1 = False Then
                Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>NEEDS RESOURCE", Criteria2:="<>AWAITING INFO", Operator:=xlAnd
            ElseIf Reports.CheckBoxAI1 = True And Reports.CheckBoxNR1 = False Then
                Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>NEEDS RESOURCE"
            ElseIf Reports.CheckBoxAI1 = False And Reports.CheckBoxNR1 = True Then
                Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>AWAITING INFO"
            End If
    End If
```